# Запрет на создание БД в MS SQL со специфическим названием

Tags: sql, sql-server

Хочу запретить создавать названия БД, где присутствуют пробелы и тире.

Т.е хочу, что бы когда пользователь пытался создать базу, то она в итоге не создавалась.

Знаю, что можно сделать через политики и триггер. Можно примеры?

Через политики почему-то у меня не получилось.

Comment: Проверил то же самое - сработало. _Хочу запретить создавать названия БД, где присутствуют пробелы и тире_ - можно триггером ещё.

Comment: @i-one, можно пример триггера?

Answer (score 1):

> Хочу запретить создавать названия БД, где присутствуют пробелы и тире.

Этого можно добиться с помощью DDL-триггера уровня сервера:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CheckDatabaseName
ON ALL SERVER
FOR CREATE_DATABASE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @evt xml, @dbName sysname;

    SET @evt = eventdata();
    SET @dbName = @evt.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName/text())[1]', 'sysname');
    IF @dbName like N'%[ -]%'
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Incorrect database name.', 16, 1);
        ROLLBACK;
        RETURN;
    END
END
```

Такое решение, правда, обладает ограниченной применимостью, ведь можно создать БД с подходящим именем

```
CREATE DATABASE [DBName];
```

и после этого переименовать

```
ALTER DATABASE [DBName] MODIFY NAME = [DB Name];
```

Запретить переименование гораздо труднее.

Можно было бы триггер назначить сразу на два события - `FOR CREATE_DATABASE, ALTER_DATABASE`. Однако `eventdata` для события *ALTER_DATABASE*

```xml
<EVENT_INSTANCE>
  <EventType>ALTER_DATABASE</EventType>
  <PostTime>2017-07-24T12:09:21.997</PostTime>
  <SPID>53</SPID>
  <ServerName>HOST</ServerName>
  <LoginName>LoginName</LoginName>
  <DatabaseName>DBName</DatabaseName>
  <TSQLCommand>
    <SetOptions ANSI_NULLS="ON" ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT="ON" ANSI_PADDING="ON" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="ON" ENCRYPTED="FALSE" />
    <CommandText>ALTER DATABASE [DBName] MODIFY NAME = [DB Name]</CommandText>
  </TSQLCommand>
</EVENT_INSTANCE>
```

содержит новое имя для БД лишь в тексте команды, а не отдельным полем. Распарсить же текст команды, чтобы вытащить новое имя БД, не совсем простая задача.